# Can I configure Ubuntu Desktop network using ip command?

Tags: networking, .desktop, ip

I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop installed. Can I change my network settings using the ip command while NetworkManager is running?

Comment: Confusing question. The `ip` command is for use in command line terminals and scripts. Your request for a "GUI" makes no sense for the `ip` command. You could do most of your network configuration via the GUI at `System settings->Network`.

Comment: @waltinator I am on a desktop system and want to know if I can use the ip command to configure the network or must I use the graphical interface. Would issuing ip commands not confic with the graphical network setup?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to  new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you. AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* use the `ip` command. But there's a few things to note:

1. It may be overwritten by NetworkManager.
2. It's not persistent.

Generally I would suggest you use `nmcli` or `nmtui` to configure the network. Those are console frontends for Network Manager, and will modify the same backend as the graphical tools.

Answer (score 1):

Since "the network" is a system-wide resource, any configuration change, done via `ip` command or GUI or purpose-written program, affects "the network" for the whole system. There are two caveats: Some changes only applied as the interface transitions from `DOWN` to `UP`; and any GUI UI suffers from WYSIAYG (What You See Is All You Get)  - if the GUI developers didn't think of "it", you can't do "it".